# Report em Smart Device

Tags: android, genexus

gostaria de fazer a geração e a impressão de um PDF em um aplicativo Smart Device Off, alguém já fez este recurso e poderia dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Ainda não temos suporte para relatórios no generador Smart Devices, mais Simplifica tem um objeto externo que permite impressão em Android.

[Pode ver aqui](http://blog.simplificasoftware.com/2013/01/impresion-desde-dispositivos-moviles.html).

Answer (score 1):

Leandro, de forma direta vale o que o Marcos disse, 
porem no exemplo que ele enviou você manda um texto para uma impressão, e não gera um pdf em si...

para a geração de pdf em Android é possivel construir um user control utilizando a seguinte documentação:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html

o incoveniente dessa abordagem é que não teríamos a conveniência do report editor do gx
teriamos que desenhar o report na mão, como demonstrado no link acima.

Mas se tiver mais interesse mande-me um e-mail passando seus requisitos que eu posso fazer este user control pra você.

Atenciosamente, Felipe.